# Unread message count inside chat app like what'app

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I know some people had already asked here about unread message count, but my issue is somewhat different.  I am developing an app that enables private chat with my customers and sellers using android studio and firebase.  I was successful in implementing the functionalities.
I want to add in-app notifications (not push notifications) in my app like WhatsApp (as shown in the red circle in the figure).  I like to show the last unread message on the top with the count.
I had used linear layout manager.setReverseLayout(true), to sort the messages, so that messages will be sorted based on date, but I didn't get the functionality to display unread messages count inside the app. Most of the literature deals with unread messages count on the app icon badge but not on in-app and about push notifications. I don't want push notifications using SMS. If some know how to get an unread message count inside the app itself, please answer. [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexMamo,.. I just had created the layout with a  bell image.. clearly don't have an idea to proceed. I just heard about 'HelpCrunch' for displaying unread message count... I am  now reading about it .. if you can refer any thing please refer